# Is there a Java user management package similar to Django auth application?

Tags: java, django, hibernate, spring

I'm looking for a java package/spring user management package that is similar to django's auth application, which provides the database models such as User and Group out-of-the-box.

I have a standard spring/hibernate application (based on Spring ROO), and I would like to use an existing User/Group/Role implementation instead of reinventing it (the actual authentication can use spring's mechanism, but I'd like to save the time implementing the user management part).

Thanks for the help

Comment: In case of spring security, I've found this link helpful: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-532

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Emmet](http://metadata.net/sites/emmet-0.6-SNAPSHOT) project may be of interest to you.  Emmet includes a custom SpringSecurity UserDetailsStore and a webapp for user account management.  Out of the box functionality includes basic user account details, roles, support for multiple identities, support password aging, self registration and password reset.  You can use it in conjunction with SpringSecurity based authentication and access control, or (at a pinch) with other "stacks".

(Emmet also provides some custom SpringSecurity authentication components, and potted wirings, but you can ignore that aspect if you like.)

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer for Emmet.

Comment: This project seems very similar to what I'm looking for. Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: This project seems to be inactive?

Comment: Yea ... totally.  I'm unlikely ever to come back to it.  And the context I developed it for is defunct as well.  Oh well.  So long Danno / Dannotate ... it was an interesting idea.

Answer (score 2):

[Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) is a full-featured and widely-used Java auth module.  While it doesn't have data models right out of the box, there is documentation provided that gives you the DDL to create the most basic tables you'd need:

[Spring Security Database Schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-schema.html)

Comment: Thanks, the db schema link you added is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

in this period I've created a new Open Source project related the RBAC and a generic solution for the user management:

[microservice-rbac-user-management](https://github.com/andreagiassi/microservice-rbac-user-management)

You can find an RBAC apis and model here ready to use and with all the documentation. Ready to be used also with Docker.

I hope this will help you.